# How to read 64-bit value into 32-bit value?

Tags: x86, converters, x86-64

For example I have a 64-bit address like this `0xffffffff81000000ul`, so how to read the address as 32-bit value?

Comment: What do you want to do with the bits that don't fit?

Comment: @Bathsheba I just want to know how the address is read into 32-bit :)

Comment: For obvious cardinality reasons you cannot do that faithfully and reliably.

Comment: Maybe you are asking how to read a 32-bit value from the memory address 0xffffffff81000000 ?

Comment: Are you looking for `mov eax, [rsi]` in assembly?  Or maybe you're using C, since you wrote a `ul` suffix on your number.  If you have a `uintptr_t`, you can cast that to a pointer.

Comment: You didn't use any language tag.  Tag this as C if that's what you mean.

Comment: @J.Daisy: ISTM that you don't want to read **the address** itself, you want to read ***from*** that address. Other comments have shown you how.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Yes :)